# Repairing DNS on a single 2k3 domain server

Tags: windows-server-2003, internal-dns

Ok we have a 2k3 server. It is our only server and does among other things DNS, DHCP, and AD. Lately we have been getting errors of no domain server found and had issues connecting to network drives. Nothing was changed or installed on the server in say a month or two prior to this issue occurring.

On the XP and up computers a restart often fixes the issue. On the 95/98* computers nothing seems to work.

I am thinking that if I reinstalled the DNS portion of the sever it might help. However there is quite a bit of confusing information on doing this when a server has AD and DNS on the same server.

*Please don't try to convince me to update. The XP computers could be updated but getting the owner to do so has been difficult. The 9x computers have custom software that depends on paralell port access that was removed in 2k and up so they are not upgradable.

Comment: `I am thinking that if I reinstalled the DNS portion of the sever it might help` - Don't randomly do things in the hopes that it will fix the problem. Troubleshoot the problem. Check the event logs on the server and the clients. Run dcdiag on the server. Check your DNS client settings on the server and the clients. What do the server and the clients use for DNS? They should be using only the server. How are the DNS client settings on the server configured?

Comment: Feel free to contact me at the email address in my profile if you'd like to discuss how I might help if you'd like to retain my services to help you troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those finding this later in this particular case the problem ended up being a bad network card.